# what is google cloud platform?

Tags: web, google-cloud-platform, google-developers-console

I am a beginner to coding and currently I was exploring about how to add google sign in to my website. I came across many platforms such as google cloud , google developers, google developer console. So I request you to explain me all this in brief and  also tell me if I use google developer console to add google sign in to my site will it be free???

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to what GCP is, I'd suggest you to read this: https://cloud.google.com/.

Also, for Google Sign In, you could use Firebase Authentication, that would be free and definitely easier than GCP. Here some references: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin

Comment: thank you very much for your answer . I am already a firebase user and i did not use firebase because i think i can only get upto 10000 users signed in in my website. So can you please tell if i the limit is over will i have to pay and if the same applies for GCP??? please help.

Comment: Firebase Auth's verifications are free and do not bill anything, unless you require a phone verification (SMS, for example). On GCP, you start paying after 50.000 monthly active users. After all, if you have 50k monthly active users, your applications should start giving you a revenue, but this is a totally different argument